# How to only extract Close prices from Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't find a method to loop over my data frame (`df_yf`) and extract all the "Close" prices and create a new `df_adj`. The df is group_by coin price.

[image]

Initially, I tried something like but throwing me error.

```
for i in range(len(df_yf.columns):
      df_adj.append(df_yf[i]["Close"])
```

Also tried using `.get` and `.filter` but throws me errors

> "list indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed
> a comma?"

EDIT!!

Thank you for the answers. It made me realize my mistake :D. I shouldn't group_by tickers so I changed it to group_by prices (Low, Close etc.) and then was able to simply extract the right columns by doing df_adj = df_yf["Close"] as was mentioned

Comment: If you want one column from the existing frame on its own (a Series) try `df_adj = df_yf["Close"]` or maybe you want to add `.to_list()` on to that for a list.

Comment: That would throw an error due to the group_by ticker- I mean I can do df_yf["BTC-USD"]["Close"] to get the close price but would like it for all 18+ tickers

Comment: It'd have been better if you added a sample from the actual dataframe to the question as text, we can look at the image, but content from the image can not be  copied. You can do `df.head().to_dict('list')` and add it to the question.

Comment: Hi it worked now with the simple df_yf["Close"] after I adjusted that table group_by :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df_adj = np.array(df_yf["Close"])
```

Answer (score 0):

dataframe from tables will use dict to extract columns, and then use `values` to get ndarray form.

```
df_adj = df_yf["Close"].values
```

Answer (score 0):

If you group by Tickers, you could use:

```
df_adj = pd.DataFrame()
for i in [ticker[0] for ticker in df_yf]:
    df_adj[i] = df_yf[i]['Close']
```

Result:

```
    Ticker1 Ticker2 Ticker3
  0       1       1       1
  1       3       3       3
```